# How can get the refreshed option values from database only when i click on select box?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the **refreshed option values from database only when i click on select box.**

Suppose two waiter open the same order panel page at same time. Then table no:2 is shown as free in both of the panel.

Now a waiter booked table no:2. Then another waiter when clicked on the select box, he will not get the table no:2 in the options.

```
<select name="table_id" class="form-control tablename">
<option disabled="disabled">Select Table</option>
<?php $result =  mysql_query("select * from rtable r
inner join table_status as ts 
on ts.status_id=r.status_id  
where ts.status!='Booked'
order by r.table_id desc")or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['table_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['table_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

[image: Select Table Image]

[table_status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCjmE.jpg)

[rtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSE7k.jpg)

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: So you can use ajax,sql and php?..Explaining what you have tried will be a good start

Comment: want to start with ajax.

Comment: Can be done using Ajax

Comment: What if two waiters click on the select box at the same time? This will happen. A solution: Submission of a table is tentative. If the table is taken a new selection must be made. This will also save you the work of writing an ajax updater for the select box (although it would be a nice feature). The best solution would give 'in place' feedback, right next to the select box. In other words, as long as a table is selected, it is taken.

Comment: don't know how to get the select event when click by mouse and then the option values loaded from database.

Comment: Have you grip on AJAX? because this can be achieved by AJAX.

Comment: tried but not succeed

Answer (score 1):

Create function in php to generate options ( sending html is not good practice but I am adjusting to this example). In this particular example i suggest to create **functions.php** file and there add **printSelectOptions** function declaration:

```
function printSelectOptions(){

  $result =  mysql_query("select * from rtable r
  inner join table_status as ts 
  on ts.status_id=r.status_id  
  where ts.status!='Booked'
  order by r.table_id desc")or die(mysql_error()); 

  echo "<option disabled='disabled'>Select Table</option>";

  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<option value=".$row['table_id'].">".$row['table_name']."</option>";
  }

}
```

Above function prints all html options for select.

Use it function in generating select **( remember that functions.php should be included in any file with usage of printSelectOptions )**:

```
<?php
//db connection code
require_once("functions.php");//here we add our function to be available in this file

?>

<select name="table_id" class="form-control tablename">
<?php printSelectOptions() ?>
</select>
```

In frontend bind Your select ( javascript code ):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

 var select=document.querySelector("select"); //this is pure selector gets first select on page

 //function sends ajax and refresh options of select
 function refreshOptions(){

     //send ajax request
     select.innerHTML="<option>Loading..</option>"; //loading info

     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.open("GET", 'yourSecondPHPScript.php');//here example url where we get updated options
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
             if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                 select.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;//set new options
             }else{
                 console.log('Error: ' + xmlhttp.statusText )
                 select.innerHTML="<option>Connection problem</option>";
             }
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.send();  

 };

 //bind our select
 select.addEventListener("focus",function(){

     refreshOptions();        

 });

});
```

Last create example **yourSecondPHPScript.php** and in it use function:

```
 <?php
 //db connection code
 require_once("functions.php");//here we add our function to be available in this file

 printSelectOptions();//outputs options
```

To be sure that users will not take the same table besides checking in focus check it again in some submit of order form. So if table was taken refresh select ( by ajax using refreshOptions() ) and show info that this table was taken.

Last thing is to secure it on server side, create some check function in php ( PHP CODE ):

```
function tableCanBeTaken($optionId){

  //this code adds **and** to query with id to check but optionId should be validate before using in query

  $result =  mysql_query("select * from rtable r
  inner join table_status as ts 
  on ts.status_id=r.status_id  
  where ts.status!='Booked'
  and ts.table_id=$optionId ")or die(mysql_error()); 


  return mysql_fetch_array($result); //if row exists - will be false if not exists row with table_id==$optionId and not booked

  }

}
```

Then use it (PHP CODE ):

```
if (tableCanBeTaken($youOptionId)){

    //here code for taking option

}else{

    //here option is taken

}
```

Comment: Connection Problem shows when clicked.. How to resolved this?

Comment: Add all db code - connections etc. Before printSelectOptions method usage.

Comment: still same problem. here i give the codes.
order.php
http://pastebin.com/92BE0w1b
yourSecondPHPScript
http://pastebin.com/qJ8KDYkr
connect.php
http://pastebin.com/f8excR1i

Comment: problem is fixed. printSelectOptions() function can not be called from another file like yourSecondPHPScript. And also needs to remove the back-slash from url.
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'yourSecondPHPScript.php');

Answer (score 0):

Have the ajax call in the focus event of the select box.In the success of the call, append the data(available tables) to the select input.Until then, leave the select box options as 'Loading. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

@Maciej Sikora

problem is fixed.  printSelectOptions() function can not be called from another file like yourSecondPHPScript.
And also needs to remove the back-slash from url.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'yourSecondPHPScript.php');
```

i just paste the same code in yourSecondPHPScript.php like below

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");

$result =  mysql_query("select * from rtable r inner join table_status as ts on ts.status_id=r.status_id where ts.status!='Booked' order by r.table_id desc")or die(mysql_error()); 
  echo "<option disabled='disabled'>Select Table</option>";
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo "<option value=".$row['table_id'].">".$row['table_name']."</option>";
      }
?>
```

Comment: I expanded my answer to be more adjusted to Your specific situation. I suggest not copy/paste code as You showed in here instead of this function printSelectOptions should be included in any file where is used. Please check how i done it by creating file functions.php and using it in both files. Coping code is always wrong. I think now my answer can be accepted.